# Leaving minimal code inside try block

Tags: scala, syntax, code-cleanup, code-structure

Consider a function `f` defined this way:

```
def f() = {
  try { g(h()) }
  catch { case _: E => j() }
}
```

The functions `g`, `h` and `j` could in fact be any code/expression.

Considering that only `h` may throw exceptions of type `E`, **how can `f` be rewritten such that only `h` is left inside the `try` block?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`scala.util.Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try) instead. Simple program I tested in ideone:

```
import scala.util.Try
object Main extends App {
    def f() = {
        Try(h()).map(g).recover { case _: Exception => j() }.get
    }

    def g(x: Any) = "g:" + x
    def h(): Any = throw new RuntimeException
    def j() = "caught"

    println(f())  // should print "g:caught"
}
```

Honestly I wouldn't write code that ends with `.get` (instead, I would propagate the `Try` throughout the codebase, if I am writing code that can throw exceptions) but this should be roughly equivalent to your example.

Comment: Thanks, but I think your answer deserves a review. Notice that in my question, in case of exception, f returns the value of j without passing to g.

Anyways, your answer looks promising! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
Try { h() } match {
  case Sucess(x) => g(x) 
  case _ => j()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def f() = Try(h()).map(g).getOrElse(j())
```

`map` over your `Try` result. `g()` will be invoked only on `Success()`. Use `getOrElse()` to supply a default on `Failure()`.

```
import scala.util.Try

def h() = if (util.Random.nextBoolean) 7 else throw new Error
def g(x:Int) = x*5
def j() = 11

Try(h()).map(g).getOrElse(j())  // returns 35 or 11
```

Answer (score 0):

If Scala `try` block could have an `else` block - just like Python's - a clean definition of `f` could be written this way:

```scala
def f() =
  try { h() }
  catch { case _: E => j() }
  else { v => g(v) }  // v is the resulting value from the try block
```

Unfortunately, Scala does not support such thing.

---

This could be a - perhaps not so clean - possible solution:

```scala
def f() = {
  val u =
    try { Some(h()) }
    catch { case _: E => None }

  u match {
    case Some(v) => g(v)
    case None => j()
  }
}
```